# Google App Engine not supported Java.io.FileOutputStream

Tags: google-app-engine

I am very new to google App engine please give me proper solution,my problem is below

when i am trying to deploy my web application to google app engine it shows me error like `Java.io.FileOutputStream restricted` in google app engine
How to fix it.Is there any setting in google app angine so that this class is supportable without changing java code,

If not what is the alternative way for this problem. Below is my error code.

```
   Uncaught exception from servlet
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted   class.
   Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
```

Answer (score 1):

On the Google App Engine lots of classes are simply not available or give you an SecurityException. You are simply not allowed to [read or write files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_Selecting_the_Java_runtime) on GAE.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, if you need some filesystem-like storage, you should look at [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) which provides streamed I/O.